# Is there a "temporary root" for Samsung phones?

Tags: root-access, samsung, bloatware

I have a Samsung stellar from Verizon.

I want to temporarily root it (I think the iPhone/iPod one is a tethered root).

After I restart my phone, I want it to act like it **never** was rooted. Ever. If I give it to my carrier, even, and they investigate it, they won't be able to find it.

Is this possible? I don't need a custom ROM or anything, I just want to remove the pre-installed crapware.

Comment: So what would your carrier think if the pre-installed crapware is no longer there -- even if no root-files are found on the device? That they forgot to install it in your case? :) By removing that crapware you already give them proff you *had* root. If you don't want that, all that's left is to de-activate that crap, as far as that's possible (even with Android 4.0+, not all apps can be deactivated if the manufacturer/carrier decided you have to keep them).

Comment: @Izzy I could just say that it was never there and they'd have no proof otherwise.

Comment: So if you rooted it, then installed an app under root, then unrooted it, the app would no longer have root permission. Also Izzy is right - If you take off some of the pre installed apps (crapware) they will know you rooted it because you need root to do that. And also it is almost impossible to remove all evidence of a root, you're better off just not rooting it, or keeping the root.

Answer (score 2):

As others said, if you remove the crapware, well, that proves the rooting.

Anyway, you can try [towelroot](https://towelroot.com) in order to gain temporary root permissions.

1. Open the app and tap three times on **welcome to towelroot**;
2. A text box should appear: substitute 1 to the last 0;
3. Click on **make it ra1n**.

This should provide you with a temporary root.